# Keras deep learning accuracy 100% problem

Tags: python, keras, sentiment-analysis

I'm going through a film classification with Keras.

The file is tagged [film review, sentiment(emotion)].

```
 # MLP for the IMDB problem
import numpy
from keras.datasets import imdb
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
# load the dataset but only keep the top n words, zero the rest
top_words = 5000
# (X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(num_words=top_words)
X_train = train_result
y_train = train_label
X_test = test_result
y_test = test_label

max_words = 500
X_train = sequence.pad_sequences(X_train, maxlen=max_words)
X_test = sequence.pad_sequences(X_test, maxlen=max_words)
# create the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(top_words, 32, input_length=max_words))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(250, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
# Fit the model
hist = model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=10, batch_size=128, verbose=1)
# Final evaluation of the model
scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=1)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))


%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, loss_ax = plt.subplots()

acc_ax = loss_ax.twinx()

loss_ax.plot(hist.history['loss'], 'y', label='train loss')
loss_ax.plot(hist.history['val_loss'], 'r', label='val loss')

acc_ax.plot(hist.history['acc'], 'b', label='train acc')
acc_ax.plot(hist.history['val_acc'], 'g', label='val acc')

loss_ax.set_xlabel('epoch')
loss_ax.set_ylabel('loss')
acc_ax.set_ylabel('accuray')

loss_ax.legend(loc='upper left')
acc_ax.legend(loc='lower left')

plt.show()
```

> OUTPUT = always Accuracy 100%

As a basic deep learning model, 
If you enable the imdb annotation, it will output normally.

I don't think the Text preprocessing process is wrong.

I downloaded the imdb.csv file directly, processed it, printed it and it shows the same graph

[IMDB_Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieG5c.png), [MYData_Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAZyZ.png) (very strange MYData graph..)

For reference, [my Csv file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BevfrSgFAayEg6AyXvFVgbRhn-uYina7)

I've classified horror movies as scary or brutal films.

[cruel, astonish] I've sorted it into tags.

Can we sort it out frankly? I've been doubting it.

I don't know if the data itself is wrong or the code is wrong.

---

Do you have any idea what's wrong?

Why is 100% accuracy always displayed?

Comment: When I run your code (with the `imdb.load_data` line uncommented), I get a testing accuracy of about 86%. So the error probably lies in your data loading. Perhaps your testing set contains garbage?

Comment: @Dion First of all, thank you for your answer, What do you mean by **garbage data**? , My Csv file consists of just a review of scary movies and a review of cruel movies. + with sentiment tag

Comment: Did you make sure that `X_test` and `y_test` contain what you think they should contain?

Comment: Please add how you load your data, and how you split it into train and test data sets.

Comment: @Dion 
Thanks! I was stupid, because it kept the tags that I added for the IMDB .csv file during the preprocessing, because there were strange values ​​in y_test, y_train! Thank you so much!